# Openlayers 3 draws over other icons

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

I am using Openlayers 3. I made an html file witch opens map of a cuntry in offline mode and allows user to draw images/segments and polygons on it. My problem is when i change the image i want to insert on the map it also draws over other points on the map and i dont understand why , any ideas ???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
                <select id="type">
                    <option value="Point">Point</option>
                    <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
                    <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
                </select>
                <select id="image_type">
                    <option value="stop_sign.png">Stop Sign</option>
                    <option value="Argentina_P-32.svg.png">Argentina</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Save Coordinates" onclick="SaveCoordinates()">
        <input type="button" value="Get Coordinates" onclick="GetCoordinates()">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var icons = [
            "stop_sign.png",
            "Argentina_P-32.svg.png"
        ];

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            //create empty vector
        });

        var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({

            layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: source
            })],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [3300000, 6000000],
                zoom: 9
            })
        });
        var features = new ol.Collection();
        var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: features,
            deleteCondition: function (event) {
                if (event.type == 'pointerup') {
                    var imageSelect = document.getElementById('image_type');
                             var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                            features: features
                        }),
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                                offset: [0, 0],
                                opacity: 1,
                                scale: 1,
                                src: imageSelect.value
                            })
                        })
                    });
                    map.addLayer(featureOverlay);
                    var l = map.getLayers().getArray();
                }
                return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) && ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
            },
        });

        map.addInteraction(modify);

        var draw;

        function addInteraction() {
            console.log(typeSelect.value);
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: features,
                type: (typeSelect.value)
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
        }
        var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

        typeSelect.onchange = function (e) {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
        };
        addInteraction();

        function SaveCoordinates() {
            var polyFeatures = featureOverlay.getSource();
            var coordsPoligon = [];
            var coordsPoints = [];
            var coordsLine = [];
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var z = 0;
            polyFeatures.forEachFeature(function (polyFeature) {
                if (polyFeature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Polygon') {
                    coordsPoligon[i] = polyFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                    i++;
                } else if (polyFeature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
                    coordsPoints[j] = polyFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                    j++;
                } else if (polyFeature.getGeometry().getType() === 'LineString') {
                    coordsLine[z] = polyFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                    z++;
                }
            });
            var markers = {
                "points": coordsPoints,
                "lines": coordsLine,
                "polygons": coordsPoligon
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:54823/LayerDataNew',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: markers
            });
        }
        var layerMarkers = [];
        function GetCoordinates() {
            $.get("http://localhost:54823/LayersDataGet", { layerId: 4 }).done(function (data) {
                layerMarkers.push(AddMarkers(data.ObjectResult));
                if (layerMarkers.length > 1) {
                    layerMarkers.splice(0, 1);
                    var l = map.getLayers().getArray();
                    if (l.length > 1) {
                        map.removeLayer(l[1]);
                    }
                }
                map.addLayer(layerMarkers[layerMarkers.length - 1]);
            });
        }
       function AddMarkers(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var object = data[i];
                if (object.Type === 1) {
                    var rnd = Math.random();
                    var style = [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                            scale: 1,
                            anchor: [0, 0],
                            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                            opacity: 1,
                            src: object.Value
                        }))
                    })
                    ];
                    var f = new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([object.Coordinates[0].X, object.Coordinates[0].Y]),
                        name: 'Point ' + i
                    })
                    f.setStyle(style);
                    vectorSource.addFeature(f);
                }
                else if (object.Type === 2) {
                    var polyArray = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < object.Coordinates.length; j++) {
                        polyArray[j] = [object.Coordinates[j].X, object.Coordinates[j].Y];
                    }
                    vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(polyArray),
                        name: 'Line ' + i
                    }));
                }
                else if (object.Type === 3) {
                    var polyArray = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < object.Coordinates.length; j++) {
                        polyArray[j] = [object.Coordinates[j].X, object.Coordinates[j].Y];
                    }
                    vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([polyArray]),
                        name: 'Polygon ' + i
                    }));
                }

            }
            var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#ffcc33',
                    width: 2
                })
            }); 
            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource,
                style: iconStyle
            });
            return vectorLayer;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you `deleteCondition` of the Modify interaction, which continuously adds new layers with the same features but new styles to the map.

I can't really understand what your trying to do, but what actually happens is this:

You have a ol.Collection: `features`. The draw interaction adds new features to this collection. Each time there's a mouseup event on a vertex, your deleteCondition function adds a new layer to the map. This layer is drawn above the others, and contains all features in the collection with the currently selected icon as a style.

I'm guessing that your intent is to set the style of just the newly drawn feature to the currently selected icon. If that's the case, listen to the `drawend` event on the Draw interaction instead, and set the style (or a property used by a style function) there.

Use only the deleteCondition option for what it's intended: to determine if a vertex should be deleted.